# Permissão arquivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Tenho um arquivo **PHP** dentro do diretório opt no Linux.

Dentro dele tenho um script com queries para atualizar um banco de dados, com senha e login de conexão do banco de dados.

Esse arquivo é setado dentro de um arquivo bash agendado no cron que manda executá-lo:

```
php /opt/script_de_atualizacao.php
```

Qual a permissão que dou nesse arquivo ?
Já que ele tem a senha e login do Mysql, seria o 755?

Comment: E a sua intenção é que o arquivo possua permissão de execução mas que os usuários não possam acessá-lo para ver os dados de acesso do banco?

Comment: Sim. Seria isso. Qual permissão posso usar?

Answer (score 13):

A coisa mais importante, geralmente, é não configurar posse e permissões desnecessárias para o funcionamento do *cron* no seu sistema operacional. Use o princípio do privilégio mínimo. Por exemplo, você não precisa rodar esse *script* como *root*, em primeiro lugar. Crie um usuário no seu sistema específico para a tarefa (assumindo [adduser](https://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser)), se for o caso, ponha-o como dono do arquivo ([chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)) e configure-o como o executor no cron. Por exemplo, em `/etc/crontab`, para rodar a tarefa 4:30 da madrugada todos os dias:

```
30 4 * * *  usuario_da_tarefa  /usr/local/bin/php -f /opt/script_de_atualizacao.php
```

Observo que, se fizer deste modo, */opt/script_de_atualizacao.php* nem precisa ser executável. Precisa apenas ser legível, para ser interpretado pelo *php*; ou seja, o modo 400 é suficiente. Ainda no exemplo:

```
# useradd -r usuario_da_tarefa
# chown usuario_da_tarefa:usuario_da_tarefa /opt/script_de_atualizacao.php
# chmod 400 /opt/script_de_atualizacao.php
```

Mais além, você provavelmente não precisa expor o usuário administrativo do seu banco no arquivo */opt/script_de_atualizacao.php*. Crie um usuário específico no banco para a sua tarefa e dê as permissões no banco necessárias a ele, como para SELECT e SHOW VIEW.

Só para completar e esclarecer ainda mais, notei confusão importante sobre permissões de acesso em arquivos na sua pergunta. Veja, ao dar `ls -l` em um diretório, você vai ver algo assim, na primeira coluna:

`- --- --- ---`

As três trincas finais indicam permissões, ao modo que o primeiro espaço isolado indica a natureza do arquivo. A primeira trinca indica permissão ao dono, a segunda ao grupo e a terceira a outros, ou seja, quem não é o dono (terceira coluna de `ls -l`) nem faz parte do grupo (quarta coluna de `ls -l`).

Você pode usar o [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) basicamente da seguinte forma: `chmod XYZ arquivo`, em que X configura permissão ao dono, Y ao grupo e Z a outros. Ambos X, Y e Z vão de 0 a 7, significando isto:

```
1 (execução),
2 (escrita),
4 (leitura),
```

e suas possibilidades de soma.

Assim, `chmod 755 /opt/script_de_atualizacao.php` significa:

Permissão 7 ao dono dele, ou seja 1 (execução) + 2 (escrita) + 4 (leitura); permissão 5 ao grupo **e a outros**, ou seja 1 (execução) + 4 (leitura). Desse modo, **qualquer usuário pode ler (e executar) o arquivo**, e não é isso que você quer, já que a segurança do seu banco está em jogo.

Dê uma olhada em [permissões de acesso em arquivos](http://wiki.inf.ufpr.br/maziero/doku.php?id=unix:permissoes_em_arquivos), para complementar.