# Verificando tabelas crashadas no MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query

Aqui na empresa existe uma estrutura com pelo menos 20 servidores, cada servidores possuem pelo menos 20 bases de dados, sendo que cada base deve possuir entre 40 a 50 tabelas. Para uma estrutura dessa, rodar o comando `check table 'nome_da_tabela';` em todas as tabelas, mesmo que por código é muito demorado.

Atualmente existe um código em PHP que percorre todos os servidores e roda o comando já citado acima, mas como disse é muito demorado, portanto gostaria de saber se quando uma tabela Crasha no MySQL, se isso gera algum log dentro do próprio MySQL que pode ser consultado ao invés de entrar tabela por tabela e verificar?

Pergunto isso, pois já li em algum lugar que na base information_schema em alguma tabela é armazenada essa informação, mas não encontrei nada que me explicasse com clareza.

Comment: Você está procurando o [checksum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html) que é o relatório do somatório de controle da tabela que é um dos teste feito `CHECK TABLE` para determinar se uma tabela está ou não danificada. O checksum funciona da seguinte maneira, toda vez que uma informação é inserida ou modificada em uma linha o DB soma todos os bytes dessa linha e guarda o resultado junto da linha. O `CHECK TABLE` ou `CHECKSUM TABLE` simplesmente refaz esse somatório linha por linha, na tabela verificada, e compara com o valor armazenado se der diferença acusa o erro

Comment: antes de postar uma resposta, já usou o comando `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE COMMENT LIKE '%crash%'` pra ver se esse resultado ajuda? Dai é possível inserir em uma tabela e usar esses dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe o programa [mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) para essa tarefa. Por exemplo, para procurar por erros nas tabelas de todas as bases (*check*, ou *-c*, é a operação padrão e pode ser omitida):

```
$ mysqlcheck -u usuario -p --all-databases
```

Ou, de bases específicas:

```
$ mysqlcheck -u usuario -p --databases db1 db2 ...
```

Observo que você não precisa expor o usuário administrativo *root*. Qualquer usuário com permissão para executar *SELECT* e *INSERT* nas tabelas é suficiente.

Se você ainda quiser fazer isso manualmente, sem o *mysqlcheck*, você pode usar nos scripts a opção *FAST* ou *CHANGED* do comando [CHECK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/check-table.html). Conforme a documentação oficial, *FAST* e *CHANGED* foram criados para verificar tabelas periodicamente. Na maioria dos casos, **FAST** é preferível. Isso já deve te ajudar. Agora vamos falar sobre registros (logs) para este propósito.

Uma forma de registrar tudo o que acontece numa sessão é usando o comando *builtin* [tee](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html):

```
mysql> tee meus_logs.txt
mysql> //COMANDOS...
mysql> notee
```

Ou, ao invocar o cliente pela linha de comando:

```
$ mysql --tee meus_logs.txt ...
```

Você também pode usar operadores de redirecionamento num sistema similar ao UNIX, mas diferentemente da opção acima, erros terminam a execução:

```
$ mysql ... < comandos.sql > meus_logs.txt
```

Pronto, daí é só processar o arquivo *meus_logs.txt* (procurar por erros). E viu, se quiser fazer um *daemon* em PHP para a tarefa, dê uma olhada em [cron e permissões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394173/permiss%c3%a3o-arquivo-php/394559#394559).